# Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipart

I have trouble with convert type "multipart"

"Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

my Code :
Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/desainkartu/action.insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String actionInsert(@Valid @ModelAttribute("data") DesainKartu data,
                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                           Model model,
                           Principal principal,
                           @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException  {
    StringBuilder fileNames = new StringBuilder();
    String url = "desainkartu/insert";
    try {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            StringBuffer errorMessage = new StringBuffer();
            List<FieldError> aList = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            for(FieldError bList : aList) {
                errorMessage.append("<div>"+bList.getDefaultMessage()+"</div>");
                url = "desainkartu/insert";
            }
            for(MultipartFile file : files) {
                Path fileNameAndPath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, file.getOriginalFilename());
                fileNames.append(file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.write(fileNameAndPath, file.getBytes());
            }
            model.addAttribute("message", errorMessage.toString());
        } else {
            try {
                data.setCreatedby(principal.getName());
                data.setCreateddate(date1);
                service.save(data);
                url = "redirect:/desainkartu/list?status=true";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                StringBuilder ste = new StringBuilder();
                ste.append(e.getMessage());
                for(StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()) {
                    ste.append(element.toString()+"\n");
                }
                log.error(ste.toString());
                model.addAttribute("message", ste.toString());
            }
        }
```

properties

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=15MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=15MB
multipart.enabled=true
```

thanks

Comment: Your `DesainKartu` has a field named `foto` of type `String`. However you are submitting that as a file. So the type doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I fix this, you can try

about entity :

```
   public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }
```

in thymeleaf form, at type="file" input we no need to add th:field="*{image}"
Just need to do like this

```
     <div class="form-group input-group has-feedback">
        <label class="col-form-label">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
```

and in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/register")
        public String createAccount(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model 
        model, HttpServletRequest request,final @RequestParam MultipartFile file, 
      RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) throws IOException {}
```